# jQuery Lightbox gallery only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, lightbox

I am trying to build my own simple jQuery lightbox gallery. My logic behind it is as follows: Only thumbnails will be shown & created at first. These link to the full size images.

```
            <section class="gallery-set">
                <a href="img/about/gallery/a1.1.jpg">
                    <img src="img/about/gallery/thumb1.1.jpg" alt=""
                    height="192" width="383">
                </a>
                <a href="img/about/gallery/a1.jpg">
                    <img src="img/about/gallery/thumb1.jpg" alt=""
                    height="192" width="383">
                </a>
                <a href="img/about/gallery/a2.1.jpg">
                    <img src="img/about/gallery/thumb2.1.jpg" alt=""
                    height="192" width="383">
                </a>
            </section>
```

Therefore, when you click on any of these thumbnails, I dynamically create an overlay-lightbox and all full size images, showing only the one that links to the thumbnail you clicked. Although the rest of the images has been created too, these are hidden for now.

```
function lightBox() {

    var gallery = $('.gallery-set'),
        overlay = $('<div/>', {id: 'overlay'});

    overlay.appendTo('body').hide();

    gallery.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var clickedThumb = $(this),
            clickedThumbPath  = $(this).attr('href'),
            clickedImg = $('<img>', {src: clickedThumbPath, alt: 'fullSizeImage', class: 'current'}),
        prevThumbs = clickedThumb.prevAll(),
        nextThumbs = clickedThumb.nextAll();

        prevThumbs.each(function() {
            var prevImg = $('<img>', {src: $(this).attr('href'), class: 'prev non-current'});
            prevImg.appendTo(overlay);
        });
        clickedImg.appendTo(overlay);
        nextThumbs.each(function() {
            var nextImg = $('<img>', {src: $(this).attr('href'), class: 'next non-current'});
            nextImg.appendTo(overlay);
        });

    overlay.show();
    })
.....
.....
}
```

Now, when you click the second thumbnail, jQuery dynamically creates all the fullsize images and this is how HTML structure looks like:
[image]

Now that I have this structure, I can easily traverse the full sized images by left and right arrows. The current image gets hidden and the next one gets shown. For this logic I am using two classes, **current** and **non-current** where the first one has set display to block and the second one to none. This piece of code is within the lightbox() function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(event) {

        var pressed = event.keyCode || event.which,
            arrow = {left: 37, right: 39};

        switch(pressed) {
            case arrow.left:
                var curr = overlay.find('.current'),
                    prev = curr.prev();
                if(curr.hasClass('current')) {
                    curr.removeClass('current').addClass('non-current');
                } else {
                    curr.addClass('non-current');
                }
                if(prev.hasClass('non-current')) {
                    prev.removeClass('non-current').addClass('current');
                } else {
                    prev.addClass('current');
                }
                break;
            case arrow.right:
                var curr = overlay.find('.current'),
                    next = curr.next();
                curr.removeClass('current').addClass('non-current');
                next.removeClass('non-current').addClass('current');
                break;
        }
    });

    overlay.on('click', function() {
        overlay.hide();
        overlay.find('img').remove();
    });

});
```

Everything works fine the first time. However, once I close the lightbox and try to open it again, the correct image opens but the arrows functionality is gone. I do not understand why - since I am dynamically creating the full sized images everytime user clicks on the gallery and putting event listeners (arrows) only once these have been created.

Just for the record, I am calling this lightbox() function from the HTML file right before the closing  tag.

Any ideas much appreciated. Also, if there's a simpler / better way of doing this, please do let me know! I don't want to use any plugin as I think this is pretty simple and straightforward. Or, I thought it WOULD BE SIMPLE I should rather say.

Comment: I think you should declare `overlay` outside the `lightBox()` function... Just a declaration like `var overlay;`. Then in `lightBox()`, give it a value... Don't `var` it. ;)

Comment: Or in `$(document).on('keyup', function(event) {`, add `var overlay=$(document).find("#overlay");`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that didn't help :/

Comment: mmm... Can you share the live link then? Because it can be hard to reproduce for me.